# Android Fragment Simple Button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, crash, fragment

Why is my application crashing on start up?

I am trying to control layout elements from the Placeholder fragment.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private Button button;
        private TextView textView;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
            button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView.setText("Button clicked.");
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);



            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    >

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please, post your error's stack trace

Comment: Don't link to the code.... Include it directly in the question

Comment: I would include directly in snippet. But it kept saying there is too much code add more details.

Comment: Well you are not supposed to just dump all your code here. You are supposed to show us the relevant bits necessary to  reproduce the problem. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to initialize `textView` and `button` in your fragment's `onCreateView`, by using `rootView` not `getActivity()`, like this:

```
textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

so your method becomes:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setText("Button clicked.");
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. Nicey Nice....It works now.